# Java's installed, but getting "Could not create the Java virtual machine"

Tags: java

Trying to install: http://syedrezaali.com/code/SuperShape2D.zip

from... http://www.syedrezaali.com/blog/?p=1119

...on WindowsXP and Windows7 machine and keep getting an error:
"Could not create the Java virtual machine"

both machines have the latest version of Java installed.

Anyone clues why?

Comment: That means that the Java executable started up, but crashed before it could initialize the runtime. Does it say anything else?

Comment: Yes, does it say anything else?

Answer (score 0):

When i want to run it, I also get that error best solution is to recompile it with the source code (witch is included in the SuperShape2D folder).

You can download a working version from here:[Recompiled SuperShape2D](http://www.mediafire.com/?iv0fs6gq810amsf)
(I just recompiled it)

Comment: Thanks @user1103589, another dumb question.  How do you ultimately create a Windows.exe file, than to install?  Or how can you install .jar file?

Comment: How do you mean install the .jar file ?

If you mean really installing, and you want .exe's .app's and such.

Have a look at Launch4J(link end of post). This is wrapper that create's an installer for your .jar file.

Also, it can make your .jar into a .exe .

Hope this helps,
Arno


 http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Also, a .jar does not need any installation, you just need to install the JVM and then (normally) it would automaticly recongnize a .jar and you just need to double click it to run it.